# vscode debugging vuejs in firefox

Tags: vue.js, debugging, firefox, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to debug my vuejs app in Firefox but so far i am unable to do it. Chrome seems to work fine, but in Firefox breakpoints do not work.

There is no error, the app just runs without stopping on breakpoints.

I am using the config from official vuejs [cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html)

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "pathMappings": [{ "url": "webpack:///src/", "path": "${webRoot}/" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  },
  productionSourceMap: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

There seems to be a lot of help available for debugging in chrome in contrast to Firefox. Therefore it will be highly appreciated by many developers like me who want to keep Firefox as their primary browser.

Comment: did you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Did this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480454/debugging-node-prime-vue-webapp-in-vs-code-not-hitting-break-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest looking at this configuration:

```json
    {
      "name": "Launch localhost",
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "launch",
        "reAttach": true,
        "firefoxExecutable": "/usr/bin/firefox",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
        "skipFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/app/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "url": "webpack:///",
                "path": "${workspaceFolder}/app/src/components/"
            }
        ]
    }
```

[Source](https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug/issues/85#issuecomment-883193812)

Comment: It does indeed work. :) Ironically, this is my own Github comment. :D I'll give you the bounty for digging it out, and I'll also add the configuration to your answer as an edit.

Comment: That is funny. Glad I found it and that it works. I approved your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I get troubles when using the debug function of Visual Studio Code too. So I use debugger of Firefox instead, it works well, satisfies all of my needs. I hope this answer may help you.

I debug my Vue.js code like this:

1. Inside the file vue.config.js (you already did this):

   module.exports = {
   configureWebpack: {
   devtool: 'source-map'
   }
   ...
   };
2. Run the Vue app in the command line using this statement: yarn serve
3. In Firefox, open Debugger tab inside Developer tools, find the src file .vue you want to debug inside the folder Webpack there, then set breakpoints to debug.
   (if you don't know where to look up the src file, you can look at my screen here: [example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzlYF.png)

Answer (score -2):

just open browser, and run your project and open you developer tools, and mark point there. you can do essay way.

here is documentation

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not specific to Vue.js

Comment: so specially for vue js only have extension not any debugger available

Answer (score -4):

Browser devtools extension for debugging Vue.js applications.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Comment: yes I know about browser extension. but i am asking for a way to set breakpoints from vscode to debug. vscode has the extension for Firefox but i am not able to configure it properly.